# Convertir un caracter a mayuscula

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

¿Es posible ingresar un char por teclado usando el método Scanner y convertir esta en mayúscula?
Tengo el siguiente código:

```
package Ejercicios;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ejercicio1 
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        Scanner Leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        int contador;
        char continuar;
        contador=0;
        System.out.println("Escriba S para Iniciar");
        continuar = Leer.next().charAt(0);
        while (continuar == 'S') {            
            System.out.println("Escriba S para continuar");
            continuar = Leer.next().charAt(0);
            contador+=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando ingreso la letra "s" en minúscula no ejecuta el bloque de instrucciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sí es posible.

Puedes usar:

```
continuar = Character.toUpperCase(continuar);
```

Hay más maneras de convertir una minúscula a mayúscula. Te invito a primero investigar por tu propia cuenta en diferentes fuentes de información y si tu respuesta no la encuentras, puedes preguntar en sitios como este. Te aseguro que para esta pregunta, en Google hay muchas respuestas mejor que la mía que te ayudarán a tu aprendizaje y lo mejor es que no tienes que esperar a que alguien te responda.

Comment: Si, eso he hecho y ya se cómo hacerlo con otro método, pero no he podido encontrar una solución que se acomode al método Scanner 